# Order Hashmap according to another list

Tags: java

Hello I have a hashmap like following :-

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap();

map.put("1","a");
map.put("2","b");
map.put("3","c");
map.put("4","d");
map.put("5","e");
```

I Have a list as following :-

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
list.add("5");
list.add("1");
list.add("3");
list.add("4");
list.add("2");
```

I Want the following output map :-

```
5 -> e
1 -> a
3 -> c
4 -> d
2 -> a
```

Comment: "Order `HashMap` according to" is already a lost cause: `HashMap` is inherently unordered. You can use a `LinkedHashMap` to preserve the insertion order. A `SortedMap` can take a `Comparator` to define a predetermined ordering, but I'm not gleaning any such order from your example.

Comment: You can iterate the list and retrieve the map's elements in that order. But you can't order a HashMap.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to iterate the entries of the map in the order defined in `list`, then you could simply do the following:

```java
for (String key : list) {
    if (map.containsKey(key)) {
        System.out.println(map.get(key));
    }
}
```

Of course, this discards any element within `map` which is not present in `list`.

Comment: I think this is one of the better answers in terms of approach (taking advantage of the ~`O(1)` lookup for hashmap), but personally I would use a direct `Map#get` (no `#contains` check) if the map shouldn't contain null values.

Comment: @Rogue Yeah, I was playing safe because of the `null`s. But indeed, I think `null` values should not be present in a `Map`, and then I would do the same as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the **LinkedHashMap**, it maintains the order.

```
import java.util.*;
public class sortmapKey {
   public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // This map stores unsorted values
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        // putting values in the Map
        map.put("1","a");
        map.put("2","b");
        map.put("3","c");
        map.put("4","d");
        map.put("5","e");

        //creating array
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
        list.add("5");
        list.add("1");
        list.add("3");
        list.add("4");
        list.add("2");
        
        //load values in a LinkedHashMap
        Map<String, String> lmap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        
        for(String val: list){
            lmap.put(val, map.get(val));
        }
        System.out.println(lmap);
    }
}
```

output will be, {5=e, 1=a, 3=c, 4=d, 2=b}

```
5 -> e
1 -> a
3 -> c
4 -> d
2 -> a
```

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` is not ordered, but you can sort the entries of the `Map` based on their index in the `List` and collect it to a `LinkedHashMap`.

```java
Map<String, String> res = map.entrySet().stream()
           .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> list.indexOf(e.getKey())))
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, 
                                              (a, b) -> b, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is probably the following.

Create a `LinkedHashMap` filled with the elements of the list and their mapping.

```
var newMap = list.stream()
  .collect(toMap(x -> x, map::get, (k, v) -> v, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `LinkedHashMap` class has already been mentioned a few times, however, this class is designed to maintain *insertion order*. But one can also use `TreeMap`, which is designed to keep an arbitrary ordering by some `Comparator` (or the *natural ordering* if the no-args constructor is used).

I have written some helper method to convert a given list to a `Comparator` which uses the order provided by the list:

```java
public static <T> Comparator<T> ofOrder(List<T> elements) {
    Map<T, Integer> comparatorMap = IntStream.range(0, elements.size())
        .collect(HashMap::new, (map, value) -> map.put(elements.get(value), value), HashMap::putAll);
    return (T left, T right) -> {
        int leftVal = comparatorMap.getOrDefault(left, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        int rightVal = comparatorMap.getOrDefault(right, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        return Integer.compare(leftVal, rightVal);
    };
}
```

With this method it's fairly easy to get a `TreeMap` with the desired ordering:

```java
TreeMap<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(ofOrder(list));
treeMap.putAll(map);
```